# Emojiture Challenge

Tags: rebus, literature, emoji

*This is the first question for the new [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #5: Literature](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/fortnightly-topic-challenge-5-literature). My inspiration source was a TV show.*

---

I wanted to read some books during holidays, so a friend sent me a list of some international classic books. Unfortunately he recently discovered [Emoji's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji), and most of his communication attempts look like this:

[image: 1. ❓ 2. 3. 4. 5. ☝️ 6. ➕ 7. 8.]

Can you help me to find out which books he recommended?

**Hint:**

> Each author has written 2 books in this list.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Got them all!

> 1) The Mysterious Island (Jules Verne)
>
>  2) Red Planet (Robert A. Heinlein)
>
>  3) The Valley of Fear (Sir Arthur Conan Doyle)
>
>  4) Journey to the Center of the Earth (Jules Verne)
>
>  5) Nineteen Eighty Four (George Orwell) (1 finger - 9 o'clock - 8 legs - 4 leaves)
>
>  6) The Sign of Four (Sir Arthur Conan Doyle)
>
>  7) Starship Troopers (Robert A. Heinlein)
>
>  8) Animal Farm (George Orwell)

Comment: I was afraid it would be too easy. 

Comment: I felt very stupid for getting 5 last by a fair bit when I had 8 as my first answer!  Enjoyed it quite a lot, though - a puzzle doesn't have to be hard to be well designed.

Comment: @Sleafar same here. Cool bananas.

Answer (score 3):

To get started:

> 1.) Jules Verne: The Mysterious Island
>  2.) Robert A. Heinlein: Red Planet
>  3.) Arthur Conan Doyle: The Valley of Fear
>  4.) Jules Verne: Journey to the Center of the Earth
>  5.)
>  6.) Arthur Conan Doyle: The Sign of the Four
>  7.) Robert A. Heinlein: Starship Troopers
>  8.)