# Emojiture Challenge - Next Generation

Tags: rebus, literature

After looking through the list of books my friend sent me [the last time](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24124/emojiture-challenge) I asked him to send me some recommendations for more recent books. Here is what I got:

[image: 1. ✞ 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8.]

I hope you can help me again.

**Hints:**

> All books are newer that those on the previous list.
> Each book was written by a different author.
> Each book was followed by a movie or TV series.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So far I've got:

> 1. Pet Semetary
>
>  2. The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo
>
>  3. Game of Thrones
>
>  4. Night Watch (several novels of the same title)
>
>  5. The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy
>
>  6. Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire
>
>  7. Hunger Games
>
>  8. The Neverending Story

Comment: Wait, how is #3 "Game of Thrones"?

Comment: @justhalf  http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=throne&defid=754918

Answer (score 6):

> 1. Pet Sematary
> 2. Girl with the Dragon Tattoo
> 3. Game of Thrones
> 4. Night Watch
> 5. Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy
> 6. Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire
> 7. Hunger Games
> 8.

Comment: Ugh. Thought about #5 so hard and should have gotten it.