# Headbanging Emojis

Tags: visual, rebus, knowledge, music, emoji

Maybe you remember my [emoji loving friend](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24124/emojiture-challenge). To make it short, he heard about the current [music challenge](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4614/fortnightly-topic-challenge-6-music) and sent me this (click for bigger version):

[image: diagram]

<sup>(Emoji art supplied by [Emoji One](http://emojione.com/).)</sup>

Comment: So this is lyrics it looks like. Or related songs?

Comment: Until I get to something better than my phone, even the big version just looks like "99 Teardrops"

Comment: @Sleafar It's not you. I'm just making a joke about my phone's tiny screen.

Comment: The dots may be letter extractions from words hinted at by the emoji - this would make the lines trace out phrases, which could be lyrics.

Comment: Does the number of small dots between some emojis relate to the number of letters we should use to find the related words?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creating the community wiki as suggested:

Numbers

> 1. Sle**epi**ng + **Ca**sh = Epica
>  2. Excl**ama**tion mark + G**ran**dfather + **The**ater = Amaranthe
>  3. Se**arch** + Mont**ene**gro + **My**anmar = Arch Enemy
>  4. **Ka**zakhstan + Ca**mel** + H**ot** = Kamelot
>  5. **Lea**f + **Ves**sel + **Eyes** = Leaves' Eyes
>  6. **Del**icious + R**ain** = Delain
>  7. S**wi**tzerland + **Thin**king + **Temp**le + S**tation** = Within Temptation
>  8. Poi**son** + Q**ata**r + **Arc**hery + Ver**tica**l = Sonata Arctica
>  9. **Night** + S**wi**tzerland + A**sh** = Nightwish

Letters

> A. **Wh**eel + Un**ite**d States + **Water** + **S**pade = White Waters
>  B. **Sa**tellite + **Cr**icket + Me**mo** + Ke**ny**a = Sacrimony
>  C. **House** + No**on** + **A**stonished + C**hill**i = House on a Hill
>  D. W**edge** + C**of**fin + Fi**st** + Wh**eel** = Edge of Steel
>  E. **The**ater + **Tra**in + **Ge**m + La**dy**bug + C**of**fin + **The**ater + **Com**et + Le**mon** + **S**pade = The Tragedy of the Commons
>  F. **A**stonished + **Day** + **For**tune + **Ghos**t + **S**pade = A Day for Ghos(t)s (I'm thinking Sleafar miscounted this one)
>  G. Th**under** + **Gr**in + K**ey** + **Skie**r + **S**pade = Under Grey Skies
>  H. **No** + **Comp**uter + **Li**ps + C**an**dy + I**ce** cream = No Compliance
>  I. S**par**k + S**ad** + Sunr**ise** = Paradise
>  J. C**ast**le + Spi**ral** + **Roman**ia + I**ce** cream = Astral Romance

Connections:

> Solid green line: connects a band to its song.
>  Dashed blue line: connects a band to a song where one of its members provided guest vocals.
>  Dotted purple line: connects a band to a song where one of its members provided guest instrumentals.
>
>  Example: Under Grey Skies (G) is by Kamelot (4) with some vocals from Charlotte Wessels of Delain (6) and tin whistle played by Troy Donockley of Nightwish (9).

Comment: This answer should be complete now.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, pretty sure I've cracked the code.  Mostly.

> The green numbered items are bands, and the blue lettered items are songs.  The solid green lines connect bands to their songs.  Not sure what the other two types of lines represent.  Musicians from other bands guesting on a song?  A producer connection?  I'm not sure because I haven't solved all of the clues yet, and Metal is not a genre of music that I'm super familiar with. (This is a headbanging puzzle, remember.)

The dots

> represent skip and take.  So, dots on the left side of an emoji mean skip that many letters, and the dots on the right side mean take the next x number of letters.  If there are no dots on the left, you just take from the beginning.

So, for example, starting with number 1 you have:

> <del>SLE</del>**EPI**NG
> **CA**SH
>  which gives you EPICA,

which is connected to letter A:

> **WH**EEL
> <del>UN</del>**ITE**D STATES
> **WATER**
> **S**PADE
>
> Epica's song [White Waters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YTzKCuE9ef0).

Number 4:

> **KA**ZAKHSTAN
> <del>CA</del>**MEL**
> <del>H</del>**OT** (tea? coffee?)
>
> KAMELOT

Letter B (this is the first one I got, actually):

> **SA**TELLITE
> **CRI**CKET
> <del>ME</del>**MO**
> <del>KE</del>**NY**A
>
>  [Sacrimony](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvWT-7l6vJU)

Letter G:

> <del>TH</del>**UNDER**
> **GR**IN
> <del>K</del>**EY**
> **SKIE**R
> **S**PADE
>
>  [Under Grey Skies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKiI85PNVTI)

Number 3:

> <del>SE</del>**ARCH**
> <del>MONT</del>**ENE**GRO
> **MY**ANMAR
>
>  [Arch Enemy](http://www.archenemy.net/)

But,

> there are no solid green lines from Arch Enemy, so I am assuming there are no songs from them, and I don't know what the relationship is between Arch Enemy and the song Sacrimony.

So that's all I've got right now, but I think it all pretty much fits.  I will try to solve some more tomorrow.  Maybe someone wants to create a community wiki answer where we can all contribute answers for the rest of the letters and numbers?

Comment: A member of 2 did guest vocals on B.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was probably something like that.